# How to write a portable shell script with error handling

Tags: bash

I have had relatively good success at writing portable, full-featured shell
shell scripts by using `/bin/sh`, for example:

```
#!/bin/sh
trap 'echo "Error on line $LINENO"; exit 1' ERR
while read LINE
do
  echo "+ $LINE"
done < file.txt
```

this works on BSD because `/bin/sh` is typically an alias to `ksh`

```
$ ls -li /bin/{sh,ksh}
26768 -r-xr-xr-x  3 root  bin  418612 Jun 18 17:41 /bin/ksh
26768 -r-xr-xr-x  3 root  bin  418612 Jun 18 17:41 /bin/sh
```

While on MacOS and many Linux distros simply symlink `/bin/sh` to `bash`

```
$ ls -li /bin/{sh,bash}
17170438 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 938832 Jul 18  2013 /bin/bash
17170540 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4 Feb 19 12:42 /bin/sh -> bash
```

If these two conditions are true then I can use a relatively rich feature set common to both KSH and BASH. On Ubuntu the default shell only supports [POSIX features](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh). Is it still possible to write a cross-platform shell script that also incorporates error handling?

**Edit (2014-08-18)**

The solution I came up with was to *auto-upgrade* the script if the given shell doesn't understand the ERR trap

```
#!/bin/sh
trap 'echo "Error on line $LINENO"; exit 1' ERR || exec bash $0 "$@"
```

This allows me to write reasonably portable shell scripts that only require bash if the default shell doesn't support KSH features.

Comment: @dan08 well, there are questions kept here, that are suitable for Ask Ubuntu far less than this one.

Comment: This question is perfectly on topic.

Comment: @Seth While it is on topic, portability is an oft-raised issue on [unix.se], and (IMO) the real experts are there, so it's more on-topic there.

Comment: I removed the extra wording describing `set +o posix` in order to stay more on topic with writing a shell script that runs on Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write a portable shell script you should stick with POSIX as that's the most reliable standard in the Unix world.

Relying in `/bin/sh` being anything but a Bourne shell is bad style and will likely break sooner or later.

As POSIX doesn't support the `ERR` trap you have to manually add your error handler to any command you want it for, using `||`. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

error(){
 echo "Error at $1"; exit 1   ## we don't have $LINENO in POSIX
}

while read LINE
do
  echo "+ $LINE"
  false
done < file.txt || error "while loop"
```

Comment: a neat trick to help if you can't have LINENO:
 `die () { 
  errnum=$1 ; shift ; 
  lineno=$(grep -n "${FUNCNAME}[ ][ ]*${errnum}" "$0" | awk '{print $1}') ;
  while msg in "$@"; do 
    printf "Error %s (line %s) : %s\n"  "$errnum" "$lineno" "$msg" ;
  done ;
}`  # 
note: $1 = in a uniq form: ex: `_nnn_` (nnn being a uniq number, identifying only 1 line in your script) $2, ...=message(s), one per line
  errnum="$1".  Use as :  `something || die __1234__ "something failed" "check this or that"`